# calculate a value through a function

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to make an engineering calculation through function which would create a new pandas series column.

Just making up some data to calculate `power`

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
from numpy.random import randint
np.random.seed(11)



def power_calc(tmp1,tmp2,flw):
  
    delta = tmp1 - tmp2
    btu_hr = 1.08 * flw * delta
    kW = btu_hr / 3412.142
    return kW


rows,cols = 50000,3
data = np.random.rand(rows,cols) 
tidx = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', periods=rows, freq='T') 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Flow','Temp1','Temp2'], index=tidx)
```

If I run the function,
`df['power'] = power_calc(df.Temp1,df.Temp2,df.Flow)`

This works to create a new column in the dataframe. What I am running into in my real world dataset is once and a while one of the temperature sensor values (`tmp1` or `tmp2`) will be out of range where I should just substitute a zero instead of some erroneous sensor value. Is there way to apply that here? I am sure there is better methods any tips greatly appreciated. For example pandas series how to iterate through the whole series and replace a bad value with a zero. That way when I run the function to calculate power my results wont be too far off.

Comment: You can assign to a column conditionally (e.g. `df.foo[df.foo > 100000] = 0`), but without more details it's hard to be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function to limit the admited values to the range of admited measures of your sensor.

Notice the difference between the `Temp2` and `power` values from `2019-02-04 17:18:00`

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
from numpy.random import randint
np.random.seed(11)

  
def power_calc(tmp1,tmp2,flw):
  
    delta = tmp1 - tmp2
    btu_hr = 1.08 * flw * delta
    kW = btu_hr / 3412.142
    return kW


rows,cols = 50000,3
data = np.random.rand(rows,cols) 
tidx = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', periods=rows, freq='T') 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Flow','Temp1','Temp2'], index=tidx)
df['power'] = power_calc(df.Temp1,df.Temp2,df.Flow)
print(df.tail(2))
#                         Flow     Temp1     Temp2         power
# 2019-02-04 17:18:00  0.249687  0.478975  0.078698  3.163391e-05
# 2019-02-04 17:19:00  0.641564  0.246557  0.244413  4.355307e-07



def df_limit_range(df, lst_filter_col, min_sensor_value, max_sensor_value):
    df_filter = df.copy()
    for col in lst_filter_col:
        df_filter.loc[df[col] < min_sensor_value, col] = min_sensor_value
        df_filter.loc[df[col] > max_sensor_value, col] = max_sensor_value
    
    return df_filter

df_filter = df_limit_range(df, lst_filter_col=['Temp1', 'Temp2'], min_sensor_value=0.1, max_sensor_value=0.9)
df_filter['power'] = power_calc(df_filter.Temp1,df_filter.Temp2,df_filter.Flow)
print(df_filter.tail(2))
#                         Flow     Temp1     Temp2         power
# 2019-02-04 17:18:00  0.249687  0.478975  0.100000  2.995045e-05
# 2019-02-04 17:19:00  0.641564  0.246557  0.244413  4.355307e-07
```